# Email copy of the row (with headers) in google sheets based on a cell value in the same row

Tags: google-apps-script, automation

I work with a restaurant chain which wants to forward the customer feedback to the restaurant manager in real time as soon as a new row is added to the sheet so that any adjustments can be made asap. Please note that feedback sheet is already live and we are currently doing this process manually. So the trigger has to be after a certain row.

We have 14 different stores and the email is to be sent to the specific manager as per the value in the column E (provider). I have zero knowledge of how this will work and so am looking for help for if this can be done with Apps Script.

I have setup a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c0Umk8VSISdNOZ_gpibRTYFZlz3P6_erR2YEw_J5n18/edit?usp=sharing) with the desired results.

Comment: How are the rows populated? Is there a google Form linked to the sheet? If so, you can bind a [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#available_types_of_triggers) and use the [event data from form submission](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) to get the row that was appended/edited, extract the data from the range and [send an email](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options) with the relevant information in the message.

Comment: It's linked with a typeform. Every time a feedback is received, a row is populated

Answer (score 0):

```
function sendFeedback() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sample Sheet");
  const [hA, ...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  let idx = {};
  let subj = "Customer Feedback"
  hA.forEach((h, i) => idx[h] = i);
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (r[idx["Sent"]] != "SENT") {
      let t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('ah3');
      t.arr = [hA];
      t.arr.push(r)
      let html = t.evaluate();
      GmailApp.sendEmail(r[idx["c_email"]], subj, '', { htmlBody: html.getContent() })
      sh.getRange(i + 2, sh.getLastColumn()).setValue("SENT")
    }
  })
}
```

'ah3.html':

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="tabledata">
       <? var vs = arr ?>
       <table>
         <? vs.forEach((r,i)=>{ ?>
           <tr>
           <? r.forEach((c,j)=>{ ?>
             <? if(i == 0) { ?>
            <th style="padding:2px 5px;font-weight:bold;border:1px solid black;"><?= c ?> </th>           
           <? } else { ?>
             <td style="padding:2px 5px;border:1px solid black;"><?= vs[i][j] ?> </td>
           <? } ?>
         <?  }); ?>
           </tr>
         <? }); ?>
       </table>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Sample Sheet:

Added Sent Column so that previously sent items will not be sent again

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | *Wie hat dir dein Essen geschmeckt?* | *Würdest du einem Freund empfehlen?* | *Wie zufrieden warst du mit unserem Service?* | *Hast du weitere Anregungen für uns?* | provider | order_type | c_email | has_app | last_order_date | Submitted At | Token | Sent |
| 2 | 5 | 10 | 5 | alles super lecker, vielen Dank! | duesseldorf-immermannstrasse | delivery |  | FALSE | 2023-06-19T10:26:34.709Z | 19/06/2023 12:45:28 | pthbtvsddpylmo26pthbtti23uajwkyv |  |
| 3 | 5 | 10 | 5 |  | frankfurt-kaiserstrasse | possale/inhouse |  | TRUE |  | 19/06/2023 08:03:38 | pc6p81zrhpi1aod14pc6pjgtsgreg9cv |  |
| 4 | 5 | 10 | 5 | Die Asia Lachs Bowl ist ein wenig langweilig mit zuviel Reis Erbsen und Gurken der gekochte zerschredderte Lachs ist auch nicht soo geil aber sonst seit ihr hammer | berlin-bahnhof-friedrichstrasse | takeaway |  | TRUE | 2023-06-17T11:01:38.804Z | 17/06/2023 18:32:19 | vzl1z2iml86pvzl12v78d2e1q58znoww |  |
| 5 | 4 | 8 | 4 | Online order and subbed an ingredient I was allergic to for something else. Unfortunately, the subbed ingredient was left out. | hamburg-brandstwiete | takeaway |  | FALSE | 2023-06-16T11:32:19.661Z | 16/06/2023 13:44:39 | wu1tbu8716adfpoejwu1tl0rzil5nm98 |  |
| 6 | 5 | 10 | 5 |  | berlin-mauerstrasse | takeaway |  | FALSE | 2023-06-16T09:27:11.460Z | 16/06/2023 11:48:15 | 45u0qzlmz0jbrew7wsmpy245u0qqvvyg |  |